# Phpstorm is unable to see Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase as a phpUnit test class

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit, phpstorm

I have a test class like that

```
require_once 'Zend/Test/PHPUnit/ControllerTestCase.php';

class MyTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase {
    public function testSomething() {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

When I try to run this test by right-clicking on it then "run myTest" PhpStorm tries to execute it instead of test it

Like that

```
C:\Zend\ZendServer\bin\php.exe C:\project\tests\MyTest.php
```

Instead of something like that

```
C:\Zend\ZendServer\bin\php.exe C:\Users\thermech\AppData\Local\Temp\ide-phpunit.php --configuration C:\project\tests\phpunit.xml MyTest C:\project\tests\MyTest.php
```

And when I try to create a PHPUnit Run/Debug configuration, the ide tell me "Error: test class is not specified or invalid"

**Edit**: My thoughts is that PHPUnit is unable to see that Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase is also a PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase (even if PHPUnit is in the include path) and I dont know why

What do I do wrong ? Is there a way to tell PhpStorm to considere Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase as a PHPUnit test ? Help !

Comment: 1) Do you have PHPUnit anywhere in your project? Without PHPUnit any class will be treated as ordinary class by IDE (and no PHPUnit-specific functionality will be offered). 2) *"tries to execute it instead of test it"* -- create Run/Debug Configuration for PHPUnit **manually** (`Run | Edit Configurations...`)

Comment: Yeah, I try that first, and the result whas the same. My thoughts is that PHPUnit is unable to see that Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase is also a PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase and I dont know why. I will add this info to my question

Comment: Could you please create a **very simple** project that would reproduce the problem and upload it somewhere? Project needs to contain all required files/libraries (so no external dependencies).